# :before only working on last element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a project which renders multiple spinners and I've noticed that on reload only the last spinner is spinning. All the elements use `:before`.

I am aware that this is fixable by removing the `:before` in the css but I would like to know why this was the case.

Here's the example, you'll see all the spinners load then when you click on the "reload" text only the last spinner will spin.

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/84879/)

Comment: no, all the spinner spin every time I click on reload

Comment: Are you clicking on the "Reload" text under the spinners? Or actually refreshing the fiddle. And what browser are you on?

Comment: I am seeing the issue described on Chrome 60

Comment: I assumed "click on reload" meant click on the text that says reload, I'm not an idiot - Firefox 56 (you know, the browser that kicks Chrome in the noods)

Comment: I was able to reproduce on Chrome, not on Firefox. Funnily enough, if you inspect the "hello" element the spinner on it works next time you hit Reload.

Comment: works on safari/ipad, doesnt work on chrome/windows

Comment: did you use debugging 101 tool ... developer tools console *`react-with-addons.js:5221 Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See Hello
printWarning @ react-with-addons.js:5221
00:18:00.389`* maybe that is significant

Comment: please don't try to remove contents. Continuously doing it may bring you many limitings and even a suspension

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're setting `before` on `.spinner` class.

Set it on `.spinner-container` class and it will work as expected

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sagarvd01/77a5k0af/)

---

*<sup>Reach doesn't work in stack snippet. That's why I added a js fiddle</sup>*

Comment: try running it and keep track on inspect element list. the class added to div is spinner-container not spinner